# Decimal em campo number (html).

Tags: html, decimal

Como colocar decimal (1,0 e 1,10) no step="0.010" de um campo type=number?já tentei fazer mas sempre os zeros ficam de fora, não é possível fazer uma altura 1.60 por exemplo, o resultado sempre é 1,6.

Comment: Isso é porque os zeros à direita não valem de nada. Se você precisa disto, vais ter que usar uma máscara ao invés de um campo do tipo `number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com este simples JavaScript você resolve isso (os *listeners* são só para exemplo, você não precisa usá-los. O código dentro deles demonstram como adicionar um `0` à direita das decimais):

```
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("change", function(){
   this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
});
```

```js
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("change", function(){
   this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="number" step="0.010" />
```

**Ou com jQuery:**

```
$("input").on("change",function(){
   $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2));
});
```

```js
$("input").on("change",function(){
   $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="number" step="0.010" />
```

Comment: boa noite, o problema continua, não pega 1,60. aparece 1,6

Comment: post do php. por que, não funciona assim??

Comment: como saber se a pessoa colocou um 1.6 ou 1.60 kkkkkk

Comment: se a pessoa tiver altura 1.6 o sistema vai salvar 1.60? acho que não rola né

Comment: resolvido, mas pode ser feito no min="1.00"(html) e definindo  step="0.010"(html). depois faz um number format contando dois dígitos para 1.60(1.6) e 3 três dígitos para 1.06. obrigado pela ajuda amigo.

Comment: vou postar aqui...

Comment: corrigindo (mim="1"). <label for="user_lic"></label><input id="user_lic" type="number" min="1" step="0.010" />